# Probability sums

Tags: probability

Given that there is a random variable X that represent a score of a game from 1 to 3, and the P(X=1) = 1/4 , P(X=2) = 1/2, P(X=3) = 1/4.

If I get 5 tries at the game, what is the probability that I would get 15 points in this game?

I tried to break this up into each tries. For me to get 15 points, I would have to score 3 points for each of my 5 tries. And the probability of me getting a score of 3 for each of my try is 1/4. But how would I calculate the probability of me getting 15 points overall?

Comment: Do you know the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)?

Comment: No I do not. My thought process was, for each trial, the probability of getting X = 3 is 1/4. If I want to get X = 3 for all 5 tries, it would be 1/4 times 5? But then I would get 1.25, and that doesn't make sense because a probability can't be more than 1. I'm really confused...

Comment: Read the article I linked.  If you need a number of things to all happen and they are all independent, the probability of them all happening is the product of the individual probabilities.  Each one makes overall success less likely, because if you fail on it you are done.

Comment: For me to get a 3 would be a probability of 1/4. And if I want a 3 for all of my 5 independent tries, each of my 5 tries would be a probability of 1/4. Would it be correct if I do (1./4)^5? So the probability that I would get 15 points in a game would be 0.00097?

Comment: That is correct.